# Ближайшие водные объекты к точке

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Всем доброго времени суток, вопрос такой. Возможно ли от Яндекс карт запросом получить список ближайших водных объектов **без указания названия**. Есть задача - есть точка (координаты известны), необходимо найти ближайший водный объект (по тз это либо река, либо озеро).
Пытался составить запрос к геокодеру с пустым полей geocode, а в поле kind указывал hydro, но в таком формате в ответ ошибка, так как поле geocode не может быть пустым, а в поле kind нельзя передать hydro(только house, street, metro, district, locality).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Геокодер возвращает координаты на запрос адреса и наоборот. Он не сможет работать с пустым запросом. Кроме того геокодер оперирует точечными координатами даже при поиске крупных объектов, он не сможет вернуть ближайшую точку берега озера или реки, например, даже если объект есть на карте и имеет имя, только центральную точку этого водного объекта.